# button click event is not triggered Angular frame work

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, click

I'm making this web app and is designing the register page for the app. I'm pretty new to Angular though.

This is the resiger.component.ts

```
  /**
   * To create a new User
   *
   * IF everything went well!!!
   * Right now there is no implement of sending a verification email so just create one for now
   *
   * @return true if user is created
   * @return false if user there is an error in input
   */
  createUser(): boolean {
    console.log('createUser() is called~');
    let created: boolean = true;
    if (this.isValidEmail()
      && this.isValidName(this.firstName)
      && this.isValidName(this.lastName)
      && this.isValidPass()) {
      this.user = {
        firstname: this.firstName,
        lastname: this.lastName,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password1
      }
      /*this.sendUser(this.user).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res); // handle success response
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err); // handle error response
        }
      );*/
    }
    else
      created = false;
    return created;
  }


  button() {
    console.log('Button clicked');
  }
}
```

This is my resgister.component.html

```
<mat-card class="register-box">
  <div>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-fab extended
              class="create-account-button"
              (click)="button()">
        Create a new Account
      </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </div>
  {{isValidEmail()}}
  {{isValidPass()}}
  {{isValidName(firstName)}}
  {{isValidName(lastName)}}
  {{createUser()}}
 </mat-card>
```

This chunk below return all true

```
  {{isValidEmail()}}
  {{isValidPass()}}
  {{isValidName(firstName)}}
  {{isValidName(lastName)}}
  {{createUser()}}
```

But when I click on create user button, there's nothing happen. No display either.
I try to change the  to  => still not working.
I do prefer to keep the  as this component is a pop up from a log-in component.
And when run, the application opened on Microsoft Edge on by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing happens because (click)="button()". I think button() should be createUser().

Button() does nothing besides a console.log

On a different note, I think you should look into [Angular Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview). Angular has build in mechanisms for validating user input (using validators).